# File will not run: "The public type EchoTest must be defined in its own file"

Tags: java

I'm just learning how to use java and I'm running to a problem.

My file is called, Echo.java, a simple script to repeat a line.

Here is my code:

```
class Echo {

    int count = 0;
    void hello(){
        System.out.println("helloooo...");
    }
}

public class EchoTest {
    public void main(String[] args) {

        Echo e1 = new Echo();
        Echo e2 = new Echo();
        int x = 0;

        while (x < 4) {
            e1.hello();

            if (x < 4){
                e2.count = e2.count + 1;
            }

            if (x < 5) {
                e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
            }
            x = x + 1;
        }

        System.out.println(e2.count);
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> The public type EchoTest must be defined in its own file

What does that mean? Do I need to rename the file type?

*** Edit ***

Humm...I've switched the class names, Echo with EchoTestDrive and the program seems to run. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single top-level public class per file.

You should have a `Echo.java` and a `EchoTest.java`, or declare the `main` function inside the `Echo` class.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm going to need to learn a little more about classes to get this down packt! Thanks :)

Comment: `or declare the main function inside the Echo class` ... "and remove the class `EchoTest`". If he keeps this (now empty) class, the error will stay.